# Attempting to import BeautifulSoup but saying that I'm trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 3

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Situation:

- Installed Python3
- Installed PyCharm
- Updated PIP to v9
- Updated setuptools to v32
- Installed BeautifulSoup4

Within Python3 when I run `from bs4 import beautifulsoup` I'm responded with:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/Users/stevendiffey/.Trash/3.6/beautifulsoup4-4.5.1/bs4/**init**.py", line 53
>   'You are trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 3.
>   This will not work.'<>'You need to convert the code, either by installing it
>   (`python setup.py install`) or by running 2to3 (`2to3 -w bs4`).'

I'm brand new to Python and have scoured for a solution, to no avail.

If anyone can help, it would be a Christmas treat :)

Comment: Is Pycharm running Python 2?

Comment: I believe so.
Project interpreter: 3.6.0

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was just a need to use the correct caps and replace:

```
from bs4 import beautifulsoup
```

with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 0):

your error should be

**/Python3.6/Lib/site-packages/bs4/init.py** is a py2 compatible module

not

/Users/stevendiffey/**.Trash**/3.6/beautifulsoup4-4.5.1/bs4/init.py

Make sure you are running /Python3.6/python.exe

try

import sys

for i in sys.path:

```
print(i)
```

make sure /Python3.6/Lib/site-packages upstream